# Convergence of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

> Prove the convergence of the following integral:
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx
> $$

I tried to use the obvious Weierstrass comparison test in the following way:

$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx \leqslant
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2}dx =
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{nx^2}dx
$$
However after thinking about a variable substitution I concluded that it would complicate the expression.

**Question:**

How should I prove the integral converges? What are your suggestions?

**Edit**:
Tried a new approach but I would like someone to check it out.
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n}\int_\limits{0}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx$ since the function is even. Substitution $\sqrt{n}x=y$
So we get after some adjustments: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\int_\limits{0}^{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{1-e^{-y^2}}{y^2(1+y^2)}dy$ Then I am not sure about the following step: $1-e^{-y^2}\sim y^2$ So we would get $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\int_\limits{0}^{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{{y^2}}{y^2(1+y^2)}dy=$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\int_\limits{0}^{n\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{(1+y^2)}dy=0$

Comment: I think it works by using the dominated convergence theorem, by considering the function : $\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}} {nx^2(1+nx^2)}1_{[-n;n]}$ which tends almost everywhere to 0 and which is dominated by a function on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @ChocoSavour             I am sorry but I am not supposed to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. Anyway thanks for your input!

Comment: @ChocoSavour           Have you got any opinion about my edit? If you have one feel free to comment.

Comment: In my opinion, there is two things : first, using asymptotic analysis is useful to determine if the integral converges or not, but not to determine the limit, cause if $f \sim g$ (and $f$, $g$ positive), I don't think that it permits to say that if the integral converges, then it converges to the same limit. However, here we have $1-e^{-y^2} \leq y^2$, so we have : $| \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \int_{0}^{n\sqrt{n}} \frac{1-e^{-y^2}}{y^2(1+y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y | \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \int_{0}^{n\sqrt{n}} \frac{y^2}{y^2(1+y^2)} \, \mathrm{d}y$, and from here we can conclude (the second one tends to 0).

Comment: @ChocoSavour                  I guess you can say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{-n}^{n}\frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}dx=0$ once $ \frac{1-e^{-nx^2}}{x^2(1+nx^2)}>0$. Since it cannot be negative and the original integral is lower than $0$ according to my resolution we could state it equals $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments indicated, We can just use the change of variables $x \sqrt{n} =y$ to get
$$ \frac{1}{n} \int_{-n}^n \frac{1-\exp(-nx^2)}{x^2(1+nx^2)} =\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \int_0^{n^{3/2}} \frac{1-\exp(-x^2)}{x^2(1+x^2)} \mathrm{d} x. $$
Noting that $$0 \leq 1- \exp(-x^2) = \int_{0}^{x^2} \exp(-t) \, \mathrm{d} t  \leq \min(x^2, \int_0^\infty \exp(-t) \mathrm{d} t) = \min(x^2,1)$$ we see that the last integral is bounded by
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\min(1,x^2)}{x^2(1+x^2)} \leq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2} \mathrm{d} x+ \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)} < \infty.$$
Thus, we can conclude that the limes is $0$ and the convergence rate is $1/\sqrt{n}$.